# When to use gosu enhancements?

Tags: guidewire, gosu

I've seen the usage of gosu enhancements a lot within Guidewire application. However, it seems to me it is being overused. Like the following examples:

- An entity querying another entity *(i.e. looks to me an entity modeling problem)*.
- An entity calling a webservice *(i.e. its beyond the purpose of the entity)*.

Are there any recommended use cases when to use enhancements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Enhancements are supposed to be used only for straight forward calculations which the business does not want to store in Database tables.
Instead of using the enhancements, I think its better to have a helper Gosu class Where we shall execute the complex queries and some logical calculations.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach is that enhancements should be used to extend existing classes with new methods or properties closely related to the original class object.

I agree that enhancements seem to be overused, that is probably because its the easy way to add some logic in existing (OOTB) parts of the Guidewire system.

Answer (score 0):

Your observations are totally valid. Enhancements should preferably be used for simple calculations where a permanent data model change is not required. Webservice calls and complex queries are recipes for performance issues when used inside an enhancement.

Enhancements can be used for standard getter/setter operations that could be obtained in a relatively straightforward calculation.